# Liftweb, Scala, loading form with ajax and lift:surround

Tags: ajax, forms, scala, lift

I have a Scala/Liftweb application, in which there is a page named "Edit Item", with URL looking like "/items/123/edit" (123 is item ID). On this page a form is displayed which is used to edit an item. I can get to this page by pressing "Edit Item" link on the "Items List" page. I am using zurb foundation CSS framework for my app, and now I decided to use Foundation Reveal plugin to load the "Edit Item" form by AJAX request and display it as a modal dialog. Everything works fine, but on the "Edit Item" page I have `<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">`, which surrounds the form with `default.html` template, in which there is the main menu, sidebar and all other stuff is located. Is there an option to get rid of `lift:surround` if the request is made by AJAX? Can I make the surround conditional? Or the only way to handle ajax-requested form without surround is to write a separate page, mention it in the SiteMap, and redirect ajax-based requests to this page?
Maybe there is an example lift application somewhere on the web which demonstrates ajax-based modal dialogs for CRUD-style item management?

Comment: I faced one more problem while solving this question: does Lift have built-in "graceful degradation" feature, for the browsers with javascript turned off (or the browsers without javascript support) to be able to serve forms in the regular way (without ajax)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to split the files up, something like this:

1. Assuming you currently have the content in `/items.html`, then
   create a file `/templates-hidden/items-content.html` and move the
   stuff you want displayed everywhere to that.
2. Replace the content you copied in `/items.html` with `<div data-lift="embed? what=/templates-hidden/items-content"></div>`.
3. Create a separate file for your AJAX popup and use the embed in step two as the only content. Or, if you want to send it as a `JsCmds.SetHtml`, you can use the `Templates("templates-hidden" :: "items-content" :: Nil)` to retrieve the content to a `Box[NodeSeq]`.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what I did until I could find a better solution. But my application is going to grow, and a lot of forms for adding/editing/configuring different kinds of things are to be added in the future. And having 3 files for each form (one for the form itself, one for ajax-based request (without surround) and one for regular requests (with surround)) does not look very comfortable. Also two of three files have to be mentioned in the SiteMap. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: And another question is: using `Templates("templates-hidden" :: "items-content" :: Nil)` how can I pass an Item ID to the snippet which serves the template? My Snippet class has parametrized constructor: `class Items(item: Item) extends PaginatorSnippet[Item] ...`. And the SiteMap entry for the "Edit Item" page looks like this: `Menu.param[Item]("Edit Item", "Edit Item", Item.find _, _.id.is.toString) / "items" / * / "edit"`. So when user visits page `/items/123/edit` the lift framework automatically finds and item with ID=123 and passes it to the snippet constructor.